# how to fix this error "opperator && can not be applied to boolean"?

Tags: java, android, int, boolean

how to fix this error , i try doing (requestCode)&&(requestCode=Result) but it did not work ?? 
code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode==12 && requestCode=RESULT_OK && data!=null){

            // start picker to get image for cropping and then use the image in cropping activity
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);

        }
```

Comment: `equestCode=RESULT_OK` should be `equestCode==RESULT_OK`

Comment: Have you tried changing  requestCode=RESULT_OK  to  requestCode==RESULT_OK ??

Comment: ...and you want `resultCode` there instead; i.e., `resultCode == RESULT_OK`.

Comment: It worked , i did not noticed it ...Thanks alot @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
(requestCode==12 && requestCode=RESULT_OK && data!=null)
```

to

```
(requestCode==12 && requestCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
```

To test value you have to **use == and not =**
I think you just made a typo.

Comment: It worked .....thanks guys